# how can mysql_query print more than one row in php/mySql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following php code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("cdcol") or die("There are no databases by that name"); 

$query = "select * from cds";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$record = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print_r($record);

?>
```

and for some reason (you will tell me why...) the output of this code is:

```
Array ( [0] => Beauty [titel] => Beauty [1] => Ryuichi Sakamoto [interpret] => Ryuichi    Sakamoto [2] => 1990 [jahr] => 1990 [3] => 1 [id] => 1 )
```

Namely, instead of getting the all table, i am just getting the first row of it. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: from the php docs [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) `Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead`. If you want all the rows, you need to loop through the results.

Comment: you should use it instead : `while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ print_r($record); }`

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_fetch_array() only gives back one row at a time.

PHP documentation: [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

You have to create a loop and loop over the mysql result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it into loop

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($record);
}
```

Comment: the mysql_* functions are marked as deprecated and should no longer be used. Use msqli_* oder PDO instead.

Comment: @Marcel Of course, it's only principle how to do it

Comment: In principle, you should use the non-deprecatted functions.